# malformed JSON string needs correction for PHP

Tags: php, c++, json, json-deserialization

I made a c++ program with combinations of cout for getting an output as a JSON string so that I can decode it in PHP using the json_decode function. I generated the string with my own logic.
I believe that there is a problem in output string but I am unable to find it even after spending hours.

The var_dump(json_decode($string, TRUE)); gives out

```
NULL
```

json_last_error_msg(); gives

```
quoted object property name expected
```

json_last_error(); gives

```
4
```

The original string I'm trying to decode using json_decode($string, TRUE) in PHP5, Platform: Ubuntu x64 14.04 LTS (apache2, php5, php5-json) installed

```
{"initUserGrid" :{    { 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } ,  { 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } ,  { 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } ,  { 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } ,  { 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } ,  { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } ,  { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } ,  { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } ,  { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } ,  { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }},"initBotGrid" :{    { 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } ,  { 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } ,  { 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } ,  { 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } ,  { 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } ,  { 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } ,  { 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } ,  { 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } ,  { 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 } ,  { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }},"moves" : {   "user" : {7 , 6} , "bot"  : {0 , 6} , "user" : {2 , 9} , "bot"  : {1 , 4} , "user" : {8 , 1} , "bot"  : {2 , 4} , "user" : {9 , 9} , "bot"  : {0 , 9} , "user" : {9 , 4} , "bot"  : {3 , 2} , "bot"  : {6 , 6} , "user" : {8 , 8} , "bot"  : {4 , 0} , "bot"  : {4 , 0} , "user" : {6 , 5} , "bot"  : {2 , 7} , "user" : {3 , 3} , "user" : {4 , 4} , "bot"  : {9 , 7} , "user" : {9 , 7} , "bot"  : {1 , 9} , "user" : {8 , 3} , "bot"  : {4 , 3} , "bot"  : {7 , 8} , "user" : {0 , 4} , "bot"  : {2 , 2} , "bot"  : {1 , 8} , "user" : {0 , 1} , "user" : {1 , 7} , "bot"  : {2 , 4} , "user" : {4 , 9} , "bot"  : {4 , 4} , "bot"  : {1 , 7} , "user" : {5 , 8} , "bot"  : {5 , 0} , "user" : {9 , 6} , "bot"  : {9 , 7} , "user" : {0 , 9} , "bot"  : {9 , 4} , "user" : {0 , 9} , "bot"  : {1 , 1} , "bot"  : {1 , 4} , "user" : {5 , 4} , "bot"  : {1 , 1} , "user" : {7 , 8} , "bot"  : {7 , 6} , "user" : {2 , 1} , "user" : {1 , 1} , "user" : {1 , 3} , "bot"  : {5 , 6} , "user" : {2 , 7} , "bot"  : {6 , 4} , "user" : {5 , 3} , "bot"  : {9 , 8} , "user" : {7 , 4} , "bot"  : {5 , 9} , "user" : {4 , 0} , "user" : {5 , 6} , "bot"  : {9 , 1} , "user" : {2 , 8} , "bot"  : {4 , 9} , "user" : {0 , 9} , "bot"  : {3 , 9} , "user" : {2 , 1} , "bot"  : {9 , 4} , "user" : {3 , 8} , "bot"  : {4 , 3} , "user" : {7 , 1} , "bot"  : {9 , 0} , "user" : {6 , 6} , "bot"  : {8 , 8} , "user" : {9 , 4} , "bot"  : {0 , 4} , "user" : {7 , 6} , "bot"  : {6 , 2} , "user" : {1 , 9} , "bot"  : {1 , 1} , "user" : {2 , 3} , "bot"  : {7 , 6} , "user" : {0 , 4} , "bot"  : {4 , 6} , "user" : {0 , 6} , "bot"  : {7 , 1} , "user" : {3 , 9} , "bot"  : {7 , 9} , "user" : {7 , 9} , "bot"  : {3 , 7} , "user" : {1 , 8} , "bot"  : {6 , 6} , "user" : {0 , 1} , "bot"  : {2 , 3} , "user" : {6 , 1} , "bot"  : {4 , 3} , "user" : {9 , 8} , "bot"  : {4 , 1} , "bot"  : {0 , 2} , "user" : {8 , 9} , "bot"  : {0 , 0} , "bot"  : {9 , 7} , "user" : {6 , 3} , "bot"  : {4 , 8} , "user" : {6 , 6} , "bot"  : {4 , 0} , "user" : {6 , 9} , "bot"  : {0 , 3} , "user" : {6 , 6} , "bot"  : {9 , 3} , "user" : {8 , 2} , "bot"  : {2 , 5} , "user" : {7 , 0} , "user" : {2 , 6} , "bot"  : {5 , 7} , "user" : {9 , 2} , "bot"  : {9 , 7} , "user" : {2 , 0} , "user" : {8 , 8} , "bot"  : {4 , 7} , "user" : {7 , 6} , "bot"  : {6 , 0} , "user" : {3 , 5} , "bot"  : {3 , 8} , "user" : {1 , 1} , "bot"  : {5 , 2} , "user" : {9 , 2} , "bot"  : {2 , 7} , "user" : {4 , 6} , "bot"  : {5 , 4} , "user" : {8 , 1} , "bot"  : {9 , 6} , "user" : {6 , 9} , "bot"  : {7 , 3} , "user" : {0 , 7} , "bot"  : {3 , 3} , "bot"  : {4 , 9} , "user" : {6 , 1} , "bot"  : {0 , 9} , "user" : {3 , 9} , "bot"  : {3 , 3} , "user" : {5 , 8} , "bot"  : {6 , 3} , "user" : {1 , 9} , "bot"  : {5 , 0} , "user" : {3 , 9} , "bot"  : {5 , 3} , "user" : {3 , 4} , "bot"  : {8 , 4} , "user" : {3 , 2} , "user" : {6 , 0} , "user" : {0 , 8} , "bot"  : {0 , 2} , "user" : {3 , 8} , "bot"  : {8 , 0} , "user" : {5 , 6} , "bot"  : {5 , 3} , "user" : {8 , 3} , "bot"  : {2 , 1} , "bot"  : {3 , 0} , "bot"  : {1 , 8} , "user" : {1 , 6} , "bot"  : {3 , 6} , "user" : {0 , 6} , "bot"  : {9 , 1} , "user" : {1 , 5} , "bot"  : {4 , 7} , "user" : {9 , 3} , "bot"  : {2 , 4} , "user" : {6 , 2} , "bot"  : {9 , 2} , "user" : {7 , 1} , "bot"  : {4 , 4} , "user" : {7 , 6} , "bot"  : {8 , 9} , "user" : {7 , 0} , "bot"  : {8 , 9} , "user" : {5 , 0} , "user" : {9 , 3} , "bot"  : {4 , 8}},"result" : "bot"}
```

Indented Version (without removing '\n')

```
{
"initUserGrid" :
{
    { 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
 ,  { 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
 ,  { 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
 ,  { 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
 ,  { 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
 ,  { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
 ,  { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
 ,  { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
 ,  { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
 ,  { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
}

,

"initBotGrid" :
{
    { 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
 ,  { 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
 ,  { 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
 ,  { 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
 ,  { 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
 ,  { 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
 ,  { 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
 ,  { 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
 ,  { 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
 ,  { 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
}

,

"moves" : {
   "user" : {7 , 6}
 , "bot"  : {0 , 6}
 , "user" : {2 , 9}
 , "bot"  : {1 , 4}
 , "user" : {8 , 1}
 , "bot"  : {2 , 4}
 , "user" : {9 , 9}
 , "bot"  : {0 , 9}
 , "user" : {9 , 4}
 , "bot"  : {3 , 2}
 , "bot"  : {6 , 6}
 , "user" : {8 , 8}
 , "bot"  : {4 , 0}
 , "bot"  : {4 , 0}
 , "user" : {6 , 5}
 , "bot"  : {2 , 7}
 , "user" : {3 , 3}
 , "user" : {4 , 4}
 , "bot"  : {9 , 7}
 , "user" : {9 , 7}
 , "bot"  : {1 , 9}
 , "user" : {8 , 3}
 , "bot"  : {4 , 3}
 , "bot"  : {7 , 8}
 , "user" : {0 , 4}
 , "bot"  : {2 , 2}
 , "bot"  : {1 , 8}
 , "user" : {0 , 1}
 , "user" : {1 , 7}
 , "bot"  : {2 , 4}
 , "user" : {4 , 9}
 , "bot"  : {4 , 4}
 , "bot"  : {1 , 7}
 , "user" : {5 , 8}
 , "bot"  : {5 , 0}
 , "user" : {9 , 6}
 , "bot"  : {9 , 7}
 , "user" : {0 , 9}
 , "bot"  : {9 , 4}
 , "user" : {0 , 9}
 , "bot"  : {1 , 1}
 , "bot"  : {1 , 4}
 , "user" : {5 , 4}
 , "bot"  : {1 , 1}
 , "user" : {7 , 8}
 , "bot"  : {7 , 6}
 , "user" : {2 , 1}
 , "user" : {1 , 1}
 , "user" : {1 , 3}
 , "bot"  : {5 , 6}
 , "user" : {2 , 7}
 , "bot"  : {6 , 4}
 , "user" : {5 , 3}
 , "bot"  : {9 , 8}
 , "user" : {7 , 4}
 , "bot"  : {5 , 9}
 , "user" : {4 , 0}
 , "user" : {5 , 6}
 , "bot"  : {9 , 1}
 , "user" : {2 , 8}
 , "bot"  : {4 , 9}
 , "user" : {0 , 9}
 , "bot"  : {3 , 9}
 , "user" : {2 , 1}
 , "bot"  : {9 , 4}
 , "user" : {3 , 8}
 , "bot"  : {4 , 3}
 , "user" : {7 , 1}
 , "bot"  : {9 , 0}
 , "user" : {6 , 6}
 , "bot"  : {8 , 8}
 , "user" : {9 , 4}
 , "bot"  : {0 , 4}
 , "user" : {7 , 6}
 , "bot"  : {6 , 2}
 , "user" : {1 , 9}
 , "bot"  : {1 , 1}
 , "user" : {2 , 3}
 , "bot"  : {7 , 6}
 , "user" : {0 , 4}
 , "bot"  : {4 , 6}
 , "user" : {0 , 6}
 , "bot"  : {7 , 1}
 , "user" : {3 , 9}
 , "bot"  : {7 , 9}
 , "user" : {7 , 9}
 , "bot"  : {3 , 7}
 , "user" : {1 , 8}
 , "bot"  : {6 , 6}
 , "user" : {0 , 1}
 , "bot"  : {2 , 3}
 , "user" : {6 , 1}
 , "bot"  : {4 , 3}
 , "user" : {9 , 8}
 , "bot"  : {4 , 1}
 , "bot"  : {0 , 2}
 , "user" : {8 , 9}
 , "bot"  : {0 , 0}
 , "bot"  : {9 , 7}
 , "user" : {6 , 3}
 , "bot"  : {4 , 8}
 , "user" : {6 , 6}
 , "bot"  : {4 , 0}
 , "user" : {6 , 9}
 , "bot"  : {0 , 3}
 , "user" : {6 , 6}
 , "bot"  : {9 , 3}
 , "user" : {8 , 2}
 , "bot"  : {2 , 5}
 , "user" : {7 , 0}
 , "user" : {2 , 6}
 , "bot"  : {5 , 7}
 , "user" : {9 , 2}
 , "bot"  : {9 , 7}
 , "user" : {2 , 0}
 , "user" : {8 , 8}
 , "bot"  : {4 , 7}
 , "user" : {7 , 6}
 , "bot"  : {6 , 0}
 , "user" : {3 , 5}
 , "bot"  : {3 , 8}
 , "user" : {1 , 1}
 , "bot"  : {5 , 2}
 , "user" : {9 , 2}
 , "bot"  : {2 , 7}
 , "user" : {4 , 6}
 , "bot"  : {5 , 4}
 , "user" : {8 , 1}
 , "bot"  : {9 , 6}
 , "user" : {6 , 9}
 , "bot"  : {7 , 3}
 , "user" : {0 , 7}
 , "bot"  : {3 , 3}
 , "bot"  : {4 , 9}
 , "user" : {6 , 1}
 , "bot"  : {0 , 9}
 , "user" : {3 , 9}
 , "bot"  : {3 , 3}
 , "user" : {5 , 8}
 , "bot"  : {6 , 3}
 , "user" : {1 , 9}
 , "bot"  : {5 , 0}
 , "user" : {3 , 9}
 , "bot"  : {5 , 3}
 , "user" : {3 , 4}
 , "bot"  : {8 , 4}
 , "user" : {3 , 2}
 , "user" : {6 , 0}
 , "user" : {0 , 8}
 , "bot"  : {0 , 2}
 , "user" : {3 , 8}
 , "bot"  : {8 , 0}
 , "user" : {5 , 6}
 , "bot"  : {5 , 3}
 , "user" : {8 , 3}
 , "bot"  : {2 , 1}
 , "bot"  : {3 , 0}
 , "bot"  : {1 , 8}
 , "user" : {1 , 6}
 , "bot"  : {3 , 6}
 , "user" : {0 , 6}
 , "bot"  : {9 , 1}
 , "user" : {1 , 5}
 , "bot"  : {4 , 7}
 , "user" : {9 , 3}
 , "bot"  : {2 , 4}
 , "user" : {6 , 2}
 , "bot"  : {9 , 2}
 , "user" : {7 , 1}
 , "bot"  : {4 , 4}
 , "user" : {7 , 6}
 , "bot"  : {8 , 9}
 , "user" : {7 , 0}
 , "bot"  : {8 , 9}
 , "user" : {5 , 0}
 , "user" : {9 , 3}
 , "bot"  : {4 , 8}
}
,
"result" : "bot"
}
```

Comment: `{ ... }` is for objects, the contents must be `"key": value` pairs. What is `{7, 6}` supposed to be?

Comment: If you're going to write your own JSON encoder, maybe you should read the JSON specification. It's at json.org.

Comment: Thanks for the responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json is invalid as you can easily check on http://jsonlint.com/ for example.

The first problem you can see on the 4th line of your prettified json:

```
{
"initUserGrid" :
{
    {
    ^ This is wrong
```

A `{` means the start of key - value pairs so after the first `{` you always need a double-quoted string.

Comment: technically it's "start of object", which then has to be followed by a key.

Answer (score 3):

Because that's not valid JSON. You have objects (`{...}`), which **REQUIRE** `"key":"value"` notation. If those were arrays (`[...]`), then they'd be valid.

What did you use to generate this "json" in the first place? A proper JSON library would never have made a mistake like that. If you're doing it manually, then... don't.

Comment: "I generated the string with my own logic" ... I fear the worst

Answer (score 0):

My Final changes after modifications. My syntax for array was wrong. This JSON string was supposed to be a record of game. There is initial grid, then moves, and result who won.

Thank you all for your answers.

```
{
    "initUserGrid": [
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]

    ,

    "initBotGrid": [
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]

    ,

    "moves": [{
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [9, 5],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [4, 2],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [5, 7],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [4, 0],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [7, 5],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [7, 5],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [8, 2],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [8, 2],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [9, 8],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [0, 8],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [7, 7],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [2, 7],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [5, 6],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [4, 0],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [9, 8],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [1, 4],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [3, 5],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [2, 1],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [8, 4],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [9, 5],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [5, 0],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [1, 1],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [5, 3],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [3, 4],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [2, 0],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [5, 7],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [9, 8],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [8, 5],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [1, 1],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [3, 9],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [5, 6],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [7, 2],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [6, 9],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [6, 7],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [1, 0],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [0, 4],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [3, 4],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [8, 6],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [7, 0],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [1, 2],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [4, 7],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [0, 1],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [4, 4],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [6, 8],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [2, 8],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [4, 8],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [9, 9],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [4, 1],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [1, 0],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [3, 0],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [3, 2],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [8, 7],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [5, 4],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [0, 6],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [9, 6],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [5, 7],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [1, 0],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [4, 8],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [9, 9],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [3, 8],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [8, 1],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [6, 4],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [5, 6],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [8, 5],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [7, 3],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [6, 7],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [5, 1],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [8, 8],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [3, 2],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [5, 4],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [3, 9],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [6, 8],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [6, 3],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [3, 9],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [4, 4],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [8, 5],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [0, 7],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [0, 9],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [9, 8],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [1, 3],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [2, 2],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [4, 3],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [7, 0],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [3, 6],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [3, 9],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [4, 5],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [2, 1],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [8, 9],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [9, 1],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [7, 1],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [3, 6],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [8, 8],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [5, 7],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [6, 7],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [2, 7],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [2, 3],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [1, 6],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [6, 0],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [7, 0],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [3, 1],
        "hit": true
    }, {
        "chance": "user",
        "point": [1, 5],
        "hit": false
    }, {
        "chance": "bot",
        "point": [5, 3],
        "hit": false
    }],
    "result": "bot"
}
```